# Next.js / firefox / chrome - favicon.ico returning 404

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, next.js, http-status-code-404, favicon

I'm developing a website on Next.js and I'm getting a 404 on firefox and chrome for my favicon.

I did change the favicon path to "icons/" folder and changed all favicon tags to the correct path:

```
<link rel="icon" href="/icons/favicon.ico" />
```

And it does load the correct favicon on the tab.

But I'm still getting a 404 on firefox's own `FaviconLoader`:

[image: firefox]

Something similar happens on Chromium, but I get no stack trace:

[image: chromium]

Does anyone know how to change the folder where the browsers expect to find the favicon?